# additional condition in a SQL query with min(Date)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the code presented below provided to me by one of the members but I do not understand how it acts:

```
select pdam.*, pr.*
from "DAMPay" as pdam left join lateral
     (select min(pr."AsigStart") as startt
      from "PolsRisc" as pr
      where pdam."PRID" = pr."Index"
     ) pr
     on true;
```

The code extracts the min of start from another table. I wanna add an aditional condition like:

```
where pdam."PAYDate" between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-30'
```

I cannot insert the condition without an error.
Also, I need only to see min(pr."AsigStart") from the pr table not all columns (pr.*).
Thanks

Comment: What did you try, and which error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add an aditional condition like:

You would typically add a `where` clause to your existing query:

```
select pdam.*, pr.*
from "DAMPay" as pdam 
left join lateral (
    select min(pr."AsigStart") as startt
    from "PolsRisc" as pr
    where pdam."PRID" = pr."Index"
) pr on true
where pdam."PAYDate" between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-30'
```

> Also, I need only to see `min(pr."AsigStart")` from the `pr` table not all columns (`pr.*`)

That's what the query does already. In the outer query, `pr` refers to the subquery (not to table `PolsRisc`). The subquery returns a single column, called `startt`, so that's `pr.*` is actually equivalent to `pr.startt`.

Comment: thanks for the query @GMB. Now it works but it seems the returned value min(start) is not correct. But your explination is fine. Thanks